# return value based on a found value with vba

Tags: excel, vba, return, find

I need to find a value based on a given input. If I use the code below, it will select the value I am searching for but I want to use the value below the selected one as a return in another worksheet. Can someone help me to adjust the code?

Kind regards.

`

```
Sub Find_First()

Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = InputBox("vul naam van leiding in")

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then

    With Sheets("scenario 1V2").Range("A1:BP150")

        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng.Offset(1), True
        
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"

        End If

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

`

Comment: By "value below the selected one" do you mean `Rng.Offset(1)`?

Comment: Yeah, I implemented that, but when I use the code I go to the cell, but I actually want to return the found value in another cell

Comment: `AnotherCell.Value = rng.Offset(1).Value`?

Comment: I do not know how to implement this in my code...

Comment: For example, if you want to return this value in the worksheet named "Foo", cell A1: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Foo").Range("A1").Value = rng.Offset(1).Value`.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382038/transfer-macro-to-udf