# Transfer macro to UDF

Tags: vba, return, find, user-defined-functions

I want the macro below transferred to a UDF but I do not know how.

I want a udf where I select the Findstring and return it in the cell where is place the udf.

Can someone help me?

```vb
Sub Find_pipe()
    Dim Findstring As String
    Dim Location As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Sub Find_First()
    Dim Findstring As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    Findstring = InputBox("vul naam van leiding in")
    
    If Trim(Findstring) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("scenario 1V2").Range("A1:BP150")
            Set Rng = .Find(What:=Findstring, _
                            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                            MatchCase:=False)
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng.Offset(1), True
                Application.Goto ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("D en L berekening").Range("A1"), True
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("D en L berekening").Range("U10").Value = Rng.Offset(1).Value
            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Function FindPipe(Findstring As String)
    Application.Volatile 'You need this if your UDF needs to update after changes in
                         '   the search range
    Dim f As Range
    If Trim(Findstring) <> "" Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("scenario 1V2").Range("A1:BP150")
            Set f = .Find(What:=Findstring, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
        End With
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            FindPipe = f.Offset(1).Value
        Else
            FindPipe = "Not found"
        End If
    Else
        FindPipe = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Note the range to be searched is hard-coded in the UDF, so Excel doesn't know to recalculate your UDF if the search range is updated.  I added `Application.Volatile` to take care of that but it may slow your workbook if you have a lot of formulas pointing to that UDF.